# Measure volume on tap of button

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

Hey below is a code that measure volume at runtime. I want a button which when tapped once starts volume as in this code and then when tapped again stops measuring.

```
local g = display.newGroup()

local function newBar()
local bar = display.newLine( 0, 0, 1, 0 ) 
bar:setColor( 0, 55, 100, 20 )
bar.width = 7
bar.y=400
bar.x=20
    return bar
end


local volumeBar = newBar()

volumeBar.y =  309
volumeBar.x = 320


function volumeBar:enterFrame ( event )

local v = 20*math.log(r:getTunerVolume())    
local MINTHRESH = 20
local LEFTMARGIN = 20
local ONE = -1
local v2 = MINTHRESH + math.max (v, -MINTHRESH)
v2 = (display.contentWidth - 20 ) * v2 / MINTHRESH
local neg =  math.max ( 20, v2 )
volumeBar.xScale =  neg * ONE
if (v >= -4) then
    volumeBar:setColor( 110,  110, 20, 200 )

elseif (v < -4) then

volumeBar:setColor( 235,  80, 80, 233)

end 

end

Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", volumeBar)

g:insert(volumeBar)
```

Help please cause here there are 2 taps that need to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Add a tap event listener to the button and call Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", volumeBar) in the tap function.

Comment: well I tried that already it didn't work :(. Hence I wanted help heres the code.

Comment: local function newBar()
 local bar = display.newLine( 0, 0, 1, 0 ) 
 bar:setColor( 0, 55, 100, 20 )
 bar.width = 7
 bar.y=400
 bar.x=20
 return bar
end

Comment: local volumeBar = newBar()
volumeBar.y =  309
volumeBar.x = 320

Comment: function volumeBar:enterFrame ( event )
local v = 20*math.log(r:getTunerVolume())    
    local MINTHRESH = 20
    local LEFTMARGIN = 20
    local ONE = -1
    local v2 = MINTHRESH + math.max (v, -MINTHRESH)
    v2 = (display.contentWidth - 20 ) * v2 / MINTHRESH
    local neg =  math.max ( 20, v2 )
    volumeBar.xScale =  neg * ONE
    if (v >= -4) then
        volumeBar:setColor( 110,  110, 20, 200 )
    elseif (v < -4) then
        volumeBar:setColor( 235,  80, 80, 233) 
    end   
end

Comment: local buzzL = ui.newButton {
        defaultSrc = "defence.png" , defaultX = "50" , defaultY = "50",
        overSrc = "defence-light.png" , overX = "50" , overY = "50",
        onEvent = myButtonHandler,
        id = "buzzL"       
}
buzzL.x=126
buzzL.y=292
buzzL:addEventListener( "tap", buzzer2 )
buzzL.buzzer2Selected = false
physics.addBody( buzzL, "static")

Comment: function switch1(event)
    if "began" == event.phase then 
       Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", volumeBar) 
    elseif "ended" == event.phase then 
       Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", volumeBar) 
    end 
 end
   
buzzR:addEventListener("tap", switch1)

Comment: Hey Joseph I added the above tap as per what you said but volume scale doesn't appear

Comment: First off, do you really expect me to make any sense of the word soup you posted into comments? Don't post code in comments. Second, if your volume bar doesn't appear then that is a problem with your display code and not with tapping. Break down your tasks one at a time, don't try to tackle all of your problems at the same time.